# iOS - Add title image in UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have created a new Tabbed application in iOS 6 
 But i want to add an image at the top so that it will be same through out my project

in `AppDelegate.m` file i added this code

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[LMSFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LMSFirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[LMSSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LMSSecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController3 = [[LMSThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LMSThirdViewController" bundle:nil];

    **UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 1024)];
    imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"LMS.jpg"];**


    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2,viewController3,nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    **[self.window addSubview:imageView];**
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

But it doesn't load any image 
 What should i do to add image any other way to implement this

Thanks, 
 Arun.

Comment: self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController; so, first view (viewcontroller1) is a rootViewController. that means currently viewcontroller1 is displayed. you can add image in window, but window is not appear at that time. comment // this line self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController; and after check

Comment: why should you add this image. what actually u want to do can u explain.
Do u want to display a custom tabbbar Image on all Views????

Comment: yes its displays the image what should i do to get may image in tabbar controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once check like this it'l work,
  add subview after calling the  `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`   method,previosly what happend you are adding the subview before loading.

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];   
    [self.window addSubview:imageView];
```